# is it necessary to choose picklist value as closed type for creating task in process builder?

Tags: process-builder, tasks

do we need to choose task picklist value of type closed for creating a task using process builder.Because the task is not getting created when I select the picklist value for Status field which is not of closed type. But when I choose the picklist value of closed type then the task is getting created. [image]

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: I don't get any error. when the status field is set to Sent to Receiver the task is not getting created but when the Status is Submission Received (Closed) then the task is getting created.